# What is the proper way to sort/search on a large dataset and return to client?

Tags: sorting, http, pagination

We have a web app which requires search/sort capabilities on a large dataset. So, naturally, traditional pagination makes this challenging (a "load 10 more" button).

On the other hand, loading **all** records and then paginating results may *look* good, and allows the user to search/sort properly the full dataset of interest, *but* whose query is quite expensive and response payload size is massive (I think 4.5MB response payload currently, which holds up Angular UI rendering time).

So what is the balance that is needed here to display a list of records that satisfies both being fully sortable and maintains a small payload size?

Comment: In general, you determine how many pages of results there are and the size of each page, and pass that info to the client along with the first page of data. To retrieve other pages, the client tells the server which page to return, and also the page size. Let the server figure out how to efficiently retrieve the requested page or pages.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely do not want to send 4.5mb down the wire especially if you have mobile users, as this would be painfully slow.

Also If 99% of users never get past page 2 or 3. Sending 1000s of results is likely to be wasteful.